# Conditioning Required Fields from others

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Is this possible to conditioning Required Fields from others in ASP.NET MVC?

So when it is true

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "ThisFieldIsRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
[Display(Name = "IsPostAddressIsVisitingAddress", ResourceType = typeof(MyModelEntities.Properties.Resource))]
public bool IsPostAddressIsVisitingAddress { get; set; }
```

then we should "turn on"

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "ThisFieldIsRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
```

of the

```
[Display(Name = "AddressLine1", ResourceType = typeof(MyModelEntities.Properties.Resource))]
public string PostAddressLine1 { get; set; }
```

Thank you!

Comment: [Check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17970584/conditional-validation-on-model-in-mvc).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25157855/how-to-remove-a-single-error-from-a-property-with-multiple-validation/25158174#25158174

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Andrei V. and Christophano

[Conditional validation on model in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17970584/conditional-validation-on-model-in-mvc)

http://foolproof.codeplex.com/

So I just added reference to that DLL and it is working fine!

```
[RequiredIfTrue("IsPostAddressIsVisitingAddress",(ErrorMessageResourceName = "ThisFieldIsRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
```